# Event fired on screenreader HTML table navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

Screen readers like Windows' Narrator have special behavior on `<table>`s or `role="grid"` elements. They have keys for navigating to the next row or column, e.g. for Narrator, CapsLock+F3 to go right to the next cell in the row, CapsLock+F4 to go down to the next in the column. Narrator puts a blue box around the current table item, and moves it with the table navigation commands. Is there any event fired when these commands are used?

I'm trying to make a virtualized div table accessible. I need to know when the screen reader hits the bottom of the DOM table so I can draw more rows. Also the grid has its own spreadsheet-style navigation for sighted users, and I'd like to sync that with the screen reader's navigation.

Comment: It's going to vary by software vendor, no?

Comment: Maybe. I'm hoping for a standard JS event. All the ARIA stuff is standardized. But I haven't found anything.